# How do I import text string as numeric in R?

Tags: r, excel

I have created a spreadsheet in Excel with `concatenate` in order to make things easier for later use. Now I want to evaluate the text strings. Doing it in Excel sounds harder than doing it in R. Therefore, I was wondering how to import and evaluate in R. Instead of what I want, I get text strings like the following.

```
     Air.Force.Falcons           Akron.Zips Alabama.Crimson.Tide
1       -.8*2-(1-.8)*1 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2
2 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2       -.8*2-(1-.8)*1 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2
3 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2       -.8*0-(1-.8)*2
4 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2
5 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2
6 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2
7 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2 -.5*0+(0)*(2*.8-1)/2
```

How do I import them as numeric or evaluate them as numeric after the fact? I've tried `as.numeric` and `colClasses="numeric"`. To recreate this, simply make a spreadsheet with formulas like `=concatenate("-5*3")`. How do I reverse this? Thanks.

Link to output of `dput(head(week15_90))`
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xCVjSff6f055PX8qEnVLh49V6TYXFQeZZzc3bofG5z4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If the text strings are mathematically complete expressions, import them as `character` and then convert them using `eval(parse(text = x))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(y) sapply(y, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))))
```

should do it.

Make sure the elements of the data frame df are strings and not factors - if they are factors you will have to convert them.

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there a way to evaluate an expression with a variable in it. For example, say the data frame has strings like `-p+2`. Is there a way to evaluate the data frame at `p=.2` for example?

Comment: If you have a variable in your R workspace named p with the value of 0.2, it will work like you want it to, that is substitute 0.2 for p in your expressions.

Comment: So as long as I have `p=.5` in my workspace, it will evaluate all `p` as .5?

Comment: It should - I tried it out and that's what it did in my example.

Answer (score 3):

Faster to unlist first your data (put it as a vector), and apply the classical `eval(parse(text=))`

```
matrix(lapply(unlist(dat),
       function(y)eval(parse(text=y))),ncol=ncol(dat))
```

Example:

```
dat <- data.frame( x=rep("-x+1",2) ,y =rep("x^2",2),stringsAsFactors=F)
> dat
     x   y
1 -x+1 x^2
2 -x+1 x^2

x <- 0.2
matrix(lapply(unlist(dat),function(y)
                         eval(parse(text=y))),ncol=ncol(dat))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.8 0.04
[2,]  0.8 0.04
```

Comment: Hi, when I try doing this, I get the following `Error in parse(text=y) : <text>:1:5: unexpected symbol` `1: Air Force` `^`. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to help you without data. Can you please add `dput(head(your_data_frame))` to your question.

Comment: Just edited. The data frame had too many characters to include.

Comment: agstudy, just figured it out. It was trying to evaluate the first column, which is actually text. Oops. Thanks for all the help.